# Is there an online bike map for the Grand Rounds bike trail in Minnesota?

Tags: us, maps, trails

- [This one](http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/byways/byways/2243/maps) is solid but not detailed.
- [This](http://www.mapmyride.com/us/richfield-mn/grand-rounds-loop-route-6299199) is just the south loop.
- [This](http://midwestweekends.com/plan_a_trip/outdoors_recreation/bicycling/bicycling_minneapolis_grand_rounds.html) says it's "available at the Longfellow House in Minnehaha Park and at rec centers and refectories along the route."
- Google just shows [a place](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Grand+Rounds+Scenic+Byway,+Minneapolis,+MN+55405/@44.972472,-93.3240562,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x52b3336aa3b83f45:0x90de51de0a3d4800!8m2!3d44.972472!4d-93.3218622).

*Edit*: Minneapolis just posted [this map](https://www.minneapolisparks.org/_asset/vc9tld/bike_tour_2016_route_map.pdf) which is pretty good.

Comment: Good work for showing your results so far.

Comment: I live in southern Minnesota, but I've rarely biked much in The Cities.  Keep in mind that this route is actually a combo of a dozen different more local routes, so it's not a single consistent thing from a mapping/signage POV, but more a sort of cooperative effort.  (But the bike trails in Minnesota are quite excellent in general, and you need not worry about getting lost or led astray.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks I was in Mpls last summer, and although I agree the bike infrastructure is superb in the area, I did manage to get myself lost on that trail in Mpls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems most of it is mapped on OpenStreetMap. You can use the Waymarked Trails website to view it on a map.

- [Waymarked Trails - Grand Rounds National Scenic Byway](http://cycling.waymarkedtrails.org/#route?id=1749619&map=12!44.9641!-93.2695)

That has a link to download it as a GPX file, so you could load that onto a GPS device, or other mapping software as required.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a printed map from

Minneapolis Parks & Recreation Board office:
2117 West River Road

Or, you can call 612-230-6400 or email info@minneapolisparks.org and they’ll send you one.

---

http://wwwdocs.minneapolismn.gov/bike/index.html  shows all the bike stuff might be overly detailed.

---

Apparently its well signposted with maps on the way.
[image]

They're not small maps!
[image]

According to [this photo blog](https://mnbiketrailnavigator.blogspot.co.nz/2012/03/trail-photo-gallery-grand-rounds-scenic_26.html)  its well marked

Answer (score 1):

The [first map the OP linked to](http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/byways/byways/2243/maps) plus a little bit of colloborating at google maps is the best source of info.

As the other poster said, there is pretty good signage, and for the majority of it, you are on a seperate bike path. There are however, a couple unusual apsects:

- The NE missing link. From about Huron and the river road, to Stinson and St. Anthony Parkway, the train is not yet completed. I believe construction has begun but I don't know when it is expected to finish. You can actually see the missing link on the map pictured in the other answer, in the Northeast section.
- A section of W River road near Franklin I believe is still closed due to the landslide a year or two ago (2014 or 15).
- There is a not very thouroughly enforced but still present 10mph speed limit on all the bike paths, which is ridiculously slow for most riders. However, with the exception of the roads around the lakes, the other roads comprising the GRSB have all been paved recently so are pretty good riding, and they have 25 mph (which no motorist obeys) speed limits on them. The roads around the lakes aren't as smooth but they are still good enough.
- The previous point is important during nice weather because it will be very busy, and much of the traffic will be families with kids rolling along at 3mph, roller bladers, and other people that aren't supposed to be on the bike path but they'll be there anyway. So expect to take the roads in nice weather anyway.

Once a year the Minneapolis Park Board puts on the [Grand Rounds Scenic Bike Tour](https://www.minneapolisparks.org/activities__events/events/minneapolis_bike_tour/), which is an opportunity to ride the whole path in a big group.

Source: Minneapolis resident.

Comment: I can confirm that West River Road is still officially closed between the U of M west bank campus and Franklin Avenue.  That said, I checked it out again two weeks ago and they are VERY close to being done. About 200 meters by the U and another 100 or so underneath the Franklin Ave bridge are actually blocked off with barriers, but everything else is finished and accessible.